# Ember.js: How to pass component attribute to jQuery callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

My component

```
{{remind-me datetime=model.reminderDatetime comment=model.reminderComment}}
```

My remind-me.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({  

    picker: $(),

    didInsertElement() {
        this._super(...arguments);

        this.picker = $('.pickadate').pickadate({
                format: 'mmm dd, yyyy',
                onOpen: function() {

                    // how to get there this.get('datetime') ?           

                }
        });
    }
});
```

How to pass component attribute datetime to jQuery callback onOpen?
Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an arrow function instead, it will bind `this` to the surrounding scope, which is the component. Try something like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({  
  picker: $(),

  didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    this.picker = $('.pickadate').pickadate({
      format: 'mmm dd, yyyy',
      onOpen: () => {
        this.get('datetime');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to previous answer.

1) You could use bind

```
                onOpen: function() {

                    // how to get there this.get('datetime') ?           

                }.bind(this)
```

2) Or store "this" in a constant in function head where content "this" content hasn't changed yet.

```
    const self = this;
    ...
    onOpen: function() {

       self.get('datetime')          

   }
```

Comment: Hmm.. Good idea! Thank you.